# How to make correct implementaion of multiple child stores created dynamically

Tags: redux

I have app where I have office list and workplace list (Workplace belongs to office). On both of them you can add notes, items (Ie. this place is small / this one has a printer / this office has one office-wide printer etc.)

Problem - To manage notes and items I plan to use shared component which renders as pop-over, and it can be more than once on screen (to compare two places for example). What I cannot figure out is how to do this correctly in redux. I cannot have one store for component. If I put one store per office / workplace - then I'm worried that I will have too much memory used (As it should take care about up to ~10000 workplaces spread between 10 offices, each of workplaces can have up to 20 items + notes). And I cannot find any other way to make store for component only - which will be created when it is shown, then it will work inside with component to make it work, and then it will be destroyed when component is closed.

Question - How to make this correctly, so I can use as much as possible from redux and it wont have local store with all data ?

[Additional info]

- From analysis (And from goal of application) I see that this lists will be used once in long period of time, when they need to load data at the beginning from the server, then make some actions around, then done.
- Overall there is big amount of small changes to items / notes, but very small amount of changes to workplaces / offices - which are checked via AJAX polling. I wanted to avoid AJAX polling / sockets for all details - because this will mean big data flow to clients

Comment: The idea is to only use one single store in redux. Why don't you simply create an array of *workplaceLists*, for example, within your store?

Comment: That's one idea, but this mean, that at extreme conditions this can has a 10k items (with inside array of 20 items) inside - and I'm just not sure if this is what I want to have. And from what I know from analysis, mostly I will need this item once (To show details) per application run, while in the same time app can run for long period of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having 10000+ items is totally fine.  In fact, this slideset on [High Performance Redux](http://somebody32.github.io/high-performance-redux/) compares the behavior of a list of 10K items with only the list component connected to Redux, vs a list of 10K items with every list item connected, and demonstrates that the 10K connected list item example is *much* faster.

Also see [Redux FAQ: Performance](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-scaling) for more information on performance, and [redux-ecosystem-links](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/component-state.md)  for links to libraries that can help implement per-component state stored in Redux.

Comment: Thanks, I thing especially second link solves my issue :-)